# Remove DOM Element Without A Specific Class With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a DIV in the DOM with jQuery by checking if is missing the class "md-panel-is-showing". However I am unable to get it to remove from the DOM and I'm not sure if I'm targeting the element incorrectly or if I am not checking if the class is missing properly. Help is appreciated.

**jQuery**

```
setTimeout(function() {     
    var $dupe = $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper[style*="z-index: 150"]');
    console.log($dupe) //this works     
    if (!$($dupe).hasClass("md-panel-is-showing")) {
        $(this).remove(); //Doesn't remove
    }
}, 3000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="md-panel-outer-wrapper md-panel-is-showing"><!-- Content --></div>
<div class="md-panel-outer-wrapper"><!-- Content --></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to actually remove it or just Hide/Show the other one?

Comment: I want to actually remove it

Comment: You can explicitly give the other div ".md-panel-not-showing" class or something else and then remove it by selecting all the elements with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not() is an inbuilt function in jQuery which is just opposite to the filter() method. This function will return all the element which is not matched with the selected element with the particular “id” or “class”. The selector is the selected element which is not to be selected.

Try this

```
setTimeout(function() {     
    $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper')
        .not('.md-panel-is-showing')
        .remove();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code. We are using [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/#not-selector) method form jQuery.

```
setTimeout(function() {     
    $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper')
        .not('.md-panel-is-showing')
        .remove();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your code refers to the global object. So, use specific target selector int this case. if there was a event handler `this` is set to the DOM element on which the listener is placed:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    var $dupe = $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper[style*="z-index: 150"]');        
    if (!$($dupe).hasClass("md-panel-is-showing")) {
        $('.md-panel-is-showing').remove(); //Doesn't remove
    }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="md-panel-outer-wrapper md-panel-is-showing">
 Md Panel Content
</div>
<div class="md-panel-outer-wrapper">
 Outer Wrapper Content
</div>
```